# How to convert this to an image to store in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, inputstream

Trying to upload a form with a file input, only getting the form fields from the input stream and not the File.Request method.

The form contains a file input and a couple of text boxes so I cant just upload the stream to the database.

I convert to string using this method

```
    int len = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.InputStream.Length);
    byte[] stream = new byte[len];
    context.Request.InputStream.Read(stream, 0, len);
    string mime = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);
```

and then split the multipart/form-data at the boundaries and read the first line of each part to see if its a file or not. You can see the full code [Here](http://snipt.org/xoyn)

A file will look something like this

```
-----------------------------17901701330412 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG00004-20101209-1704.jpg" 
Content-Type: image/jpeg 

�����ExifII* ����(1�2�i��Research In MotionBlackBerry 9105HHRim Exif Version1.00a2010:12:09 17:03:59 ��n�0220�v���� � ��� �2010:12:09 17:03:59���    $ &&$ #"(-:1(+6+"#2D36;=@A@'0GLF?K:?@>  >)#)>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>��!������ }!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz������������������������������������������������������������������������� w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������� ?�`��ⳓ5��f)¤b��a�BS�Sb�)Xz�֝�q�"s�K�PA���}F7&��Vm��GӬ��%]� Uҵ�Z7��h�`�@&i ��i��MKB�P��r���-�B|ϛ=3Yٶ ��
```

and a field will look something like this

```
-----------------------------17901701330412 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent" 

clientphotos
```

Parsing the field is easy, and getting the image content is easy, but then saving that in to the database so i can read it back out as an image, isnt so easy.

I have tried `byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawdata);` but the output isnt correct.

Has anyone any ideas how to take the image content and save it to a `byte[]` as it should be?

---

UPDATE

The first line is from getting the image from `context.Request.Files[name].InputStream.Read(data, 0, fs);`

The second line is using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawdata);`

The third line is using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rawdata);`

Obviously the first line is correct and works.

[image: SQL Result]

For now Im just using the first line to get the result and it'll probably stay that way unless someone can teach me how to read it from the input stream.

---

UPDATE

Found a nice place to share the code [Source Code](http://snipt.org/xoyn)  The trouble is on line 49 which for now just reads the `Request.Files`

Comment: It is indeed an image, so __do not__ convert it to any form of Text.

Comment: If I leave it as a string I get "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't store the image as text, store in its raw binary form.  If you HAVE to store binary data as text you will need to encode it with Base64, but its going to be alot bigger than it needs to be.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=287324

```
byte[] encData_byte = new byte[data.Length];
encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);    
string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
return encodedData;
```

You will also need to do the reverse to get it back into a usable image format.  A much better solution would be to store the binary image in a blob/binary field type in the database.

EDITED: Just reread your post and I see your data is already in base64, just store than in the database?

EDITED AGAIN: The Initial Question has been edited a number of times, I believe I answered the question but now the question has changed through a number of iterations and my initial answer is now less applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get the content as a *string*.  Ideally, you should have a `varbinary(max)` column to store this data (there's also a file storage option that I haven't tried before in SQL Server 2008).  Here's how you'd read the data into a `byte[]` to store in SQL Server:

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
var buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
using (var stream = file.InputStream)
{
    var bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead < file.ContentLength)
    {
        bytesRead += stream.Read(
            buffer, bytesRead, file.ContentLength - bytesRead);
    }
}
```

As far as Opera goes, I'm not familiar with the issue you brought up.  Maybe you could post a link explaining what you mean by "Opera has to upload in base64 using `FileReader`."  If you do still have to process a Base64 string, here's how you'd convert it to a `byte[]`:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    var base64Str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan, The OP hasn't specified that they're directly using ADO.NET to store things in SQL Server.  If an ORM is in use, then they may need a byte array.

Comment: Opera doesn't support FormData() yet, so you have to use FileReader.GetDataAsURL() which converts it to base64.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Opera doesn't support FormData() yet."  I'd be very surprised if Opera didn't let you upload files like every other web browser.  Maybe you should post what your HTML/JS looks like that does the file uploading.